# Google Universal Analytics detailed funnel tracking not possible anymore?

Tags: checkout, google-analytics, magento-1.9.2.1

Before, the funnel tracking was working with the following setup.

```
   /checkout/cart/
   /checkout/onepage/
   /checkout/onepage/opc-billing/
   /checkout/onepage/opc-shipping/
   /checkout/onepage/opc-shipping_method/
   /checkout/onepage/opc-payment/
   /checkout/onepage/opc-review/
   /checkout/onepage/opc-review-placeOrderClicked
```

But after I upgraded to 1.9.2.1, I can only track

```
/checkout/cart/index.php
/checkout/onepage/index.php
```

these steps.

Is it not possible anymore to track other steps such as payment?

Comment: It is possible to do this, make sure you have universal analytics enabled and configuted correctly both in Magento and in Google. You may also find this module useful https://github.com/fooman/googleanalyticsplus

Comment: It is configured correctly. But only tracks cart. checkout page (without any detailed steps tracked), and success page.